# How To Extract Nested HTML Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, html-parsing

I need to extract the price using BeautifulSoup for the HTML code below.

```
<div class="price-original">
  <span class="product-price-amount">
    <span class="notranslate"> £899.89</span>
  </span>
<div>
```

I'm unable to use the code below as there are several price instances on the web page using the same html syntax.

```
price1 = soup.find('div', class_='price-original').find('span', class_="notranslate").text.strip().replace("£","").replace(",","")
print('Price:', price1)
```

For this reason I need a way to extract based on all 3 html elements as this results in a unique HTML instance.

Comment: can you share URL for better understanding!

Comment: Is there something consistent about the price-original instance that you want? For example: is it always the third instance? is it always the last instance? is it always wrapped in a unique element? It may help to share an example URL as well.

Comment: Sample URLs:
https://www.costco.co.uk/Electronics-Security/Televisions-Projectors/Televisions/Samsung-QE75Q80AATXXU-75-Inch-QLED-4K-Ultra-HD-Smart-TV/p/354811 
https://www.costco.co.uk/Garden-Sheds-Patio/Garden-Structures/Gazebos-Pergolas-Conservatories/Yardistry-12ft-x-12ft-37-x-37m-Cedar-Gazebo-with-Peaked-Aluminium-Solid-Roof/p/1500084

If we used the sample code that i provided it would pick up incorrect prices. Hence, this is why my thoughts of using 3 elements would avoid such issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a cursory review of the site, it looks like the price you are interested in (i.e., the final price of the main product on the page) is inside a different html based on whether the product is discounted or not.

Assuming the your `soup` actually contains this information, for discounted products, try using

```
soup.select_one('div.product-price-container span.you-pay-value')
```

For non-discounted products, try:

```
soup.select_one('div.product-price-container span.product-price-amount > span.notranslate')
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the syntax for the non-discounted products using 3 elements. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
soup.find('span', class_ = 'notranslate').string
```

Instead of going through the `div>span>span` tree one-by-one.
This will give you `' £899.89'`, and you can format it however you like.